# how to solve cross border height and margin issue

Tags: html, css

how i can solve the height and margin  issue in cross- browser  in following simple css. in internet explorer and Firefox the height of div elements are greater then specified  as per screen size also margin between header to other div elements or footer to other element is uneven . 
**or any website reference form where i understand solution more deeply  **  . thanks in advance

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) 
{

  html ,body  
{
width : 100% ;
height :100% ;
font-size : 1rem ;
}

.header ,.footer
{
display : table-row;
background : white ;
height : 10% ;
width : 100% ;
overflow : auto ;
} 
.left
{
display : table-row;
background : red ;
height : 26.66666666666667%;
width : 100% ;
overflow : auto;

}
 .center
{
display : table-row;
background :blue ;
height : 26.66666666666667%;
width : 100% ;
overflow :auto ;
}
.right
{
display : table-row;
background : gray ;
height : 26.66666666666667%;
width : 100% ;
overflow : auto ; 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve most CSS cross-browser issues, try with a CSS reset. You can get the latest ones from [here](http://cssreset.com/).

I recommend you *normalize.css*, as I have used it before and it's great for fixing these kind of problems. But test all of them and check out which one cover your needs.

Comment: thanks @Antonio , but this is not helping . as it confusing me more  ....